# sscanf long hex number into long long int

Tags: c, int, long-integer, scanf

I have long hex number, e.g. **a3dafc126e**(10 characters long) which I want to read and convert to decimal number using sscanf:

```
long long int timestamp=0;
result = sscanf(msgPtr,"%10x", &timestamp); //msgptr contains the string a3dafc126e
printf("%lld\n",timestamp);
```

However the result is

> 3673952878

which corresponds to **dafc126e**

Can you tell me, what am I doing wrong, that scanf reads only 8 hex characters instead of 10?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`"%10x"` is for reading `int` value, and your `int` size may be 4 bytes.

To read `long long int` value, please use `sscanf(msgPtr,"%10llx", &timestamp);`

If your compiler complains or it didn't work, try `sscanf(msgPtr,"%10I64x", &timestamp);`

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the `I64` conversion specifier is non-standard C, but MS-C extension.

Comment: Also I personally want to mentioned that I upvote this although I read the phrase "*it didn't work*" ... ;-)

Comment: Note: The "10" limits the numbers of characters scanned to 10 and is not needed for general usage.

Comment: Is there a solution that works for GCC? Because neither of those do.

Comment: @KatasticVoyage What is your GCC version? Why do you think they don't work? `scanf(msgPtr,"%10llx", &timestamp);` works on [GCC 4.4.7](https://wandbox.org/permlink/zE2Ls4KNyVe7yuov). Setting to C99 mode (via `-std=c99` option) may be required in some environments.